# Would Stack Overflow benefit from forcing feedback?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, feedback

Users commonly get no feedback on their answers, especially when answering questions by low rep users. I.e. no accepts, upvotes, downvotes or comments. If the question has enough views, other users will upvote your answer, but commonly these questions only have a handful of views.

I find this to be really discouraging. So I was wondering if we could do something about that, such as not allowing a user to post a new question until he's given feedback to all the answers of his previous question.

In addition to this, it would be nice if it were easier to follow up on your old answers, e.g. by providing a visual indication in the list of answers that the OP has given feedback on the answer.

Comment: Is anyone else disappointed that this isn't about a way to punch bad users in the face remotely?

Comment: "Force feedback" usually refers to controller vibration in games.

Comment: When I read the title, I thought the question was going to be about game pads.  I must say I'm a little disappointed.

Comment: No no no no no no no no no. No. OH HECK NO. No.

Comment: I was hoping this would be about new Jedi powers.

Comment: I'm sorry about the disappointment, but controller vibration on SO just wouldn't make sense. However, it would be awesome!

Comment: I agree this is a bad idea, but it's a good question.  Why all the downvoting?

Comment: @AdamRackis On Meta Stack Overflow, a feature-request's score affects the attention it may receive for implementation. Thus, downvotes often indicate a disagreement that such a feature should be implemented.

Comment: I see.  Thank you @Grace Note for clarifying.

Comment: Looks like questions still get plenty of feedback, though.

Answer (score 22):

My limited experience with forcing people to provide feedback is that it leads to generally useless feedback.

Comment: I don't think it would be useless. They simply just have to decide if the answer was helpful or not and optionally why. I'd consider that useful feedback.

Comment: @Erik When a user wants to ask a question they need an answer to quickly, and the system stops them until they vote or comment on all the answers to their previous questions, they're not going to spend time figuring out if they deserve a particular vote or not - They're just going to hit them all randomly to get it over with so they can move on to the important task at hand - getting an answer to their new question.

Comment: I resent these accusations; I'm quite capable of providing useless feedback *without* being forced to do so.

Comment: @Aarobot I'm sorry, but your feedback is generally useful.

Comment: +1 for no particular reason. I just felt like explaining my vote, that's all.

Answer (score 3):

Stack Overflow, while having a game-like scoring system, is not a game.

This community exists to ask and answer questions. If you take away a users ability to ask a question, this community then becomes useless to that user. Questions and answers persist for years after creation, and we're here to provide help to the Stack Overflow community, which will eventually turn up on search engine results and help others in the future.

Who cares about score? It sounds like you do.

Obviously it doesn't hurt to gently remind these users that we have a system in place for upvoting and accepting answers, but they shouldn't be punished to the point of censorship simply for wanting answers, and perhaps not wanting to participate in the community to the level that you seem to expect. **Assuming the questions and answers are of decent quality, I don't see this as an issue**.

Answer (score 2):

When asking a question not every answer or comment is useful or worth providing feedback, so forcing a OP to provide feedback is a poor solution.

Secondly, just because the original asker did not accept or up-vote an answer, doesn't mean it wasn't useful to someone who viewed the question.

If there is a user that doesn't respond to comments asking for clarification then down-vote or vote to close (or both).

If you answer a user repeatedly and get no response and question is one that few others could benefit from, then try to focus on other questions instead.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my intent. Only the OP would be required to provide feedback on the answers.

Comment: @Erik, I see now. Updated by answer.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with other post. Force feedback is not a great idea.

But maybe if we could make characteristics of a healthy account, we would be able to design a dashboard to evaluate your account.

The accept rate is a first step toward this idea. But it may be improved

Are you posting enough answer?
What is your ratio of given upvotes and received upvotes?
What is the average length of my answer.
How much do I get downvoted ?
Am I not rewardful on some questions?

I guess we can pick good queries from data.stackexchange.com to install them as statistics on the user page?

Comment: I like this suggestion and asked for some additional stats on users thinking that "Accept Rate" was a first step, but this request was not viewed well:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90741/add-a-question-answer-ratio-below-the-accepted-stats-on-questions-for-the-asker

Comment: +1 for recognizing the problem and suggesting a different solution.